# converting image file into byte array using bitmap

Tags: android

I want to convert the image file into `byte[]` array format. I used this code

```
   Bitmap bm = getBitmapFromLocalPath(file1.getPath(),1);
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object
   bm.recycle();
   byte[] image = baos.toByteArray();
```

//method

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromLocalPath(String path, int sampleSize)
    {
        try
        {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //  Logger.e(e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

It showing error like

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20200324_121621.jpg (Permission denied)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
    Process: com.example.multiupload, PID: 5477
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: How do you get file1. Can you share.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException` Your bitmap is null.

Comment: E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20200324_121621.jpg (Permission denied) -- Make sure you have necessary permission if you are reading from file

Answer (score 0):

To load a file in memory declare a byte array with the size of the file. Then read the bytes of the file in that array.

Usable for all files.

Especially dont use Bitmap and BitmapFactory classes for image files. They will change the bytes of the file.